# UI's for multiple resolutions

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm having a hard time understanding how to separate UI layouts for phones and tablets since resolutions between the two is becoming more and more the same. Suppose the following:

Nexus 5: 1080p display
Nexus 7 (2012): 1280x800 display
Nexus 7 (2013): 1920x1200 display

In the above list, we have two hi-res display and one lower.

In Android, is there a way to specify layouts only for tablets? The reason I ask is because I would like to have **landscsape** layouts for tablets and **portrait** layouts for phones. It's hard nowadays to do this just on screen-size alone simply because many phones and tablet of today share the same screen sizes and dpi resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have approached this is the past is to have a values.xml file inside sw600dp called 'tablet'. Read that value in and lock the orientation horizontal if the value reads true, otherwise lock the orientation portrait using [setOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29). You'll need to specify both landscape and portrait layout files.

Before embarking on this approach, I would strongly advise you read the developer guidelines on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using the methods declared in the "[Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)" topic.

In particular this seems germane:

> The reason designing for 7" tablets is tricky when using the
>   generalized size groups is that a 7" tablet is technically in the same
>   group as a 5" handset (the large group). While these two devices are
>   seemingly close to each other in size, the amount of space for an
>   application's UI is significantly different, as is the style of user
>   interaction. Thus, a 7" and 5" screen should not always use the same
>   layout. To make it possible for you to provide different layouts for
>   these two kinds of screens, Android now allows you to specify your
>   layout resources based on the width and/or height that's actually
>   available for your application's layout, specified in dp units.